# Softbody and collision on same object

Tags: collision, soft-body

For simplicity I want to make a hand able to touch a head in a way that hand will stay as is, but head will be deformed. But for unknown reason it does not collide (figure is one object with armature and with softbody and collision).
[image: hand touch head]

Yet, when I create another standalone object and assign it a collision it works.
[image: cube touch head]

Do you know what can be an issue? Or how can I proceed?

Thank you

Comment: If one object, collision physics doesn't matter; you need "self collision" set up in the soft body physics.  (But really, consider separating these objects.)

Comment: I was also thinking to separate them, but let's say it's gonna be something complicated like human and I would like to rigify it, then I think it would be a little bit complicated :(